# how to use v model if using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

how to use v-model on vuex,
in this case only to show modal box when button is clicked
in this vuex also have separate to module

this is index module

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import authentication from './authentication'
import products from './products'
import projects from './projects'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    baseUrl: '/api',
    // baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3333/api',
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    authentication,
    products,
    projects,
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState(),
  ],
})
```

and this is my module

```
import HTTP from '../http';

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state:{
        dialog: false,
    },
    getters: {
        dialog(state){
            console.log(state.dialog)
            return state.dialog
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        closeCard(state){
            state.dialog=false;
            console.log(state.dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

i have try map state and map getter both not function
and this is my vue code

```
v-model="dialog"      
width="500"
```

i have try use map state or map getter but both not working

```
import Test from '/components/Test'
  export default {
    components:{
      Test
    },
    computed: {
      dialog:{
        get() {
          return this.$store.state.dialog.products
        },
      },
      map State('products',[
        'dialog'
      ]),
    },
    methods:{
      map Actions('products',[
        'close Card',
      ])
    }
  }
```

and this is my error

```
Computed property "dialog" was assigned to but it has no setter.
found in
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly binding a computed property to a v-model is a bad practice as a computed value doesn't have a default setter.

you will need to implement a setter for your computed value. you can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

you should implement a state action that changes the value of the `dialog` property and then call it in your setter (and set it to `true` or `false`, depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are typo's in your code while called vuex handlers

```
import {mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'; // check this line
import Test from '/components/Test'
  export default {
    components:{
      Test
    },
    computed: {
      dialog:{
        return this.dialog;
      },
      ...mapState('products',[ // check this line
        'dialog'
      ]),
    },
    methods:{
      ...mapActions('products',[ // check this line
        'closeCard', // check this line
      ])
    }
  }
```

Also note that you shouldn't directly bind a computed property to a v-model